# restrict page without variable , only open if coming from a page or site

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

page-one.php code

```
<?php
//page-one.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page_one'] = time();
?>
hello this is page 1 go to page 2

<a href="www.domain.com/page-two.php">Page 2</a>
```

page-two.php code

```
<?php
//page-two.php
session_start();

//Check to see if session variable exists.
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_one'])){
    //Does not exist. Redirect user back to page-one.php
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit;
} ?>

this is page 2
```

Works perfect but I have 2 questions:

1. what if i delete page-one bcz i want to show page 2 to all vistors who are coming on page 2 by clicking a link
2. or what if user is coming on page-two through google.com , in this case how page-two will pass page_one variable

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense, but for your specific questions:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_one']) &&
   strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'google') === false &&
   strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], 'google') === false &&
   file_exists('page-one.php')
{
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit;
}
```

- Check if the session variable is not set
- Check if `HTTP_REFERER` is not `google`
- Check if `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is not `google`
- Check if `page-one.php` has not been deleted

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not reliable as it may be wrong, a proxy server or empty and `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` is not guaranteed to be set or reliable.

With the previous caveats in mind, you can see if someone came from another site by checking:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_one'] &&
   !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] &&
   !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
{
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit;
}
```

If you add a get parameter to all links then it's easier:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/page-two.php?link">Page 2</a>
```

Then:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page_one'] && !isset($_GET['link'))
{
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: please can you guide me how i can apply session for current user on this code if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location:404.php');
    exit;
}